# how to get parent div tag if exist

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

i want to extract an most recent ancestor div tag of a link which is `<a></a>` tag

**sample html**

> id's are not part of html just for reference

```
   <div id=2>
    <div id=1>
      <p></p>
      <a></a>
    </div>
   </div>
```

output:div(id=1)

```
  <div id=3>
     <span>
        <a></a>
     </span>
  </div>
```

output:div(id=3)

python code which am using to print its parent

```
for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//body//a[@href]'):
    href=link.get_attribute('href')
    print link.find_element_by_xpath('..')
```

> instead printing parent i want print its most recent parent div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath, the `..` expression returns the immediate parent of the current context node.

If you want the closest ancestor node with a specific tag you should use the `ancestor` axes like so:
`./ancestor::div[1]`.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking got the answer